# when i export numeral data to del file from DB2, it lost accuracy

Tags: db2, export

Server is centOS7, db2 version is v11.1_linuxx64_expc.
On the other sever(also centOS7),I installed db2 client(centOS7 && v11.1.4fp5_linuxx64_client).

Test case：

```
create table TEST_REAL( c_double DOUBLE, c_real REAL) data capture changes;

insert into TEST_REAL values(-1.79E+308,3.402823e+38);
```

Remote export, details is as follow:

```
db2 catalog tcpip node p115 remote $ip server $port
db2 catalog db database at node p115
db2 connect to database user $user using &password
db2 export to $path/filename.del of del select * from TEST_REAL
```

data export success. then I check the filename.del, it is

```
-1.79000000000000E+308,3.40282E+038
```

Scientific counting , and lost the last 3 (**3.40282E+038** , compare with **3.402823e+38**),
how can i get accuracy data when i export data to del file?

Comment: What is returned when you SELECT * from TEST_REAL?

Comment: when select, it returns1790000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 and 340282306073709650000000000000000000000

Comment: So, from your perspective, is the result of the SELECT expected?

Comment: the result of the SELECT is expected，but the result of export is not expect

Answer (score 2):

Based on this support document "[Some considerations about the literal expressions of the floating point numbers on DB2 CLP, Import, Export](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/some-considerations-about-literal-expressions-floating-point-numbers-db2-clp-import-export)" that experience is expected. That support document also links to this [definition of number types in Db2](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=list-numbers).

A proposed solution is to use the IXF file format. It stores the numbers in binary format and does not convert to strings.

Comment: The question shows a floating-point-literal for a REAL datatype, that is larger than the documented maximum REAL value for Db2-LUW v11.1.  As an approximation, it is unsurprising that there are difficulties.  Chose your datatypes with care. If you need unlimited / arbitary decimal precision and scale, then do not use DOUBLE/FLOAT/REAL.

Comment: the IXF file format works. tks!

Comment: Please mark as answered